# Do JS variables have a scope if the function that declares them is never called?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables, lexical

In this code, how many variables are in the global scope, and how many are in the local scope of the `greet` function?

```
var foo = 42;
var bar = 43;

function greet(name) {
  greeting = 'Hello';
  return greeting + ' ' + name;
}
```

I believe there are two global variables (`foo` and `bar`) and 0 local variables. Since the function never gets called, `name` and `greeting` don't get declared so I would say that they are not in the global or local scope.

What do you think? Can `greeting` and `name` have a scope if the function `greet()` is never invoked?

Comment: Since JavaScript files are typically loaded dynamically, there's no way to know whether the function will ever be called or not. It's not called in this snippet, but there could be other code that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a theoretical question along the lines of "if a tree falls in the forest...".

The answer depends on whether you are analyzing the problem from a static lexical perspective vs the dynamic execution environment.  For the latter, your analysis is accurate, although.  If the code above is executed, there will be three identifiers defined in the global space, the two vars and the function.  The greeting var and name argument will not "come into existence".

That said, if I were in a code review evaluating this statically, I would have to ask "well isn't there a purpose to defining the function greet"?  The assumption must be that it is eventually intended to be called - otherwise why write it (or for that matter, any of the code above). And as such, the use of that function would definitely introduce a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Source - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

> The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution
>   context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables
>   declared outside any function, global.

The variables `foo` and `bar` are declared at the top. So they will be assigned directly to the window object (global scope).

> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a
>   global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the
>   assignment is executed.
>
> Undeclared variables do not exist until the code assigning to them is
>   executed.

The variable `greeting` is not declared and is present within the function `greet` which is not called. So, this will not create the variable `greeting` until the function is called and if called it will create `greeting` as a global variable.

`name` is not a variable, it's a parameter and acts like a placeholder.

In short, there are two global variables - `foo` and `bar` and if function `greet` is invoked, then there will be three global variables `foo`, `bar` and `greeting`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can greeting and name have a scope if the function greet() is never invoked?

Yes, `name` exists already in the local scope as although the function wasn't executed yet, it was still parsed.

`greeting` however will only exist when the function gets called, but wether its in the global scope is not relevant as its just bad practice to have implicit globals.